# Variance of mean of two independent normally distributed values

Tags: normal-distribution

If I have two measurements (assumed to come from normal distribution) `X1 = 250` and `X2 = 260` where variances are `V1 = 5` and `V2 = 6` (variance could be thought as the uncertainty in the measurements). Now the average of the two is `m = 255` but what is the resulting variance of this average? Is it possible to calculate this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Answer (score 1):

It's not a silly question, but the concepts should be clear. If we denote your random variables as $X_1$ and $X_2$, the average will be $\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$, and we can find the variance of it via a simple calculation noting that the two RVs are independent:
$$\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}\right)=\frac{\operatorname{var}(X_1)+\operatorname{var}(X_2)}{4}=\frac{5+6}{4}=\frac{11}{4}$$ 
This calculation has nothing to do with the means of $X_1,X_2$, as well as the measurement values.

Informally, variance of an unknown $X_1$ can be non-zero. However, variance of a known $X_1$ is $0$ because it is known and therefore constant. So, variance of $X_1=250$ will be $0$, and it actually means something like $\operatorname{var}(X_1|X_1=250)$, mathematically, which is $0$. Measurement random variables have non-zero variance, but the measurement itself is fixed and have no variance (e.g. it is 250 always since you measured it).